# How to hide 'non-user' stack frames in Delphi call stack window?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe2, callstack, toolsapi

Is it possible to hide/collapse stack frames, which does not have source code, and correspondingly, are not marked with these blue dots, in Delphi Call Stack?

Just for reference, Visual Studio is able to do this:

> In managed code, by default. the Call Stack window hides information for non-user code. The following notation appears instead of the hidden information:
>
> [< External Code>]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx

Will be nice if solution will work with Delphi XE2.

**UPDATE**

It can be some 3rd-party expert, or even code using ToolsAPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the very best of my knowledge, the Delphi IDE has no equivalent to the VS feature you describe.

Comment: As I expected :(
Perhaps there are any experts which can do this?

Comment: Perhaps there are. I don't know of any. You can try a websearch I guess. But asking for us to find a third party tool takes this question into off topic territory.

Comment: Are you serious thinking I didn't? Of course I did, with zero result though :(
Perhaps I used wrong words, then I will be thankful if you insight me with yours

Comment: It is simple: If you searched and didn't find any, then probably there are no experts which can do this.

Comment: The call stack window only displays the call stack for the current thread so you _could_ simulate the behavior you describe by running all "non-user" code on a separate thread. If you do this you would become a target of hatred for all Delphi programmers everywhere. Your name would be used as a curse word and people would spit on the ground and the mention of your code... but hey, life's full of trade-offs.

Comment: @Kenneth Hardly. The call stack is hierarchical. You can't really move things like Win32 message dispatch into some other thread. It's all synchronous.